# What is the difference between palindrome permutation and permutation?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I've seen coding questions to check whether a strings is a permutation of a palindrome, other times to check whether a string is a permutation of another string. Not sure I see the difference between the two. If a string is a permutation of a palindrome, both of them need to have the same length also the count of each character in both strings should be the same. The very same criteria can be said about a string after permutation. Are there any intrinsic differences between palindrome permutation and permutation from algorithm point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two questions typically differ based on how they’re framed. Usually, the string permutation question is asked as

> Given a string w and a string x, check whether w is a permutation of x.

In that sense, you know what both strings are, and you just need to see whether the character counts match (or whether they have the same sorted order, etc.)

The palindrome permutation problem is typically asked as

> Given a string w, determine whether there is a string x where x is a palindrome and w is a permutation of x.

So in this case, you’re just given a single string w and need to figure out whether somewhere out there there’s a palindrome that it’s a permutation of. This problem is different, since you don’t have an explicit target string to compare against and you need to have the creative insight of counting up the counts of each character to see whether there are exactly zero or one characters that appear an odd number of times.

The general problem of “is w a permutation of x?” ceases to be interesting if you reframe it as “is w a permutation of some string?” because the answer is an immediate “yes,” and the problem of “is w a permutation of some palindrome?” loses its charm if you reframe it as “is w a permutation of the palindrome x?” because it’s essentially the same as the general permutation problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the fact that strings that are not palindromes can have permutations. Thanks